# Proving a convergence relationship between two sequences

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, real-numbers

Let $a_{n}$ a sequence of real numbers. Let $\sigma_n= \frac{a_1+a_2+...+a_n}{n}$. Suppose that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \sigma_n=A.$
Prove that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log n}  \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a_j}{j}=A$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to Math SE. What have you tried on this problem?

Comment: I can't add an image, but I try use convergence cauchy

Answer (score 8):

I'd start from [Abel Summation Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Method),

$$\begin{align}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n} \frac{a_j}{j} &= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac{1}{j} - \frac{1}{j+1}\right)(a_1+\cdots+a_j) + \frac{1}{n}(a_1+\cdots+a_n)\\&= \sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma_j}{j+1} + \sigma_n\end{align}$$

Since, $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sigma_n = A$ (exists) and hence $|\sigma_n|$ is bounded, (by, $C > 0$ say) we may argue that.

$\displaystyle \left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma_j}{j+1}\right| \le C\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j+1} < C \log n$

Hence, the limit $\displaystyle \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{\log n}\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma_j}{j+1}$ (exists) and equals $B$ (say).

By applying the [Stolz-Cesaro Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem),

$$B = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sigma_n/(n+1)}{\log (n+1) - \log n} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \frac{\sigma_n}{\log \left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n+1}} = \lim\limits_{n\to \infty} \sigma_n = A$$

Comment: Well done!  Great use of Stolz-Cesaro!  +1

Comment: $ Ckeck \ my \ Work \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log n}  \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a_j}{j}=A\\
Let \
S_n= \sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{a_j}{j}=A, \ So \\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{1}{\log n} s_n=A \\
 | \frac{1}{\log n+m}S_{n+m}- \frac{1}{\log n}S_n | \\
 = |  \sum_{k=1}^{n+m}\frac{a_k}{k} - \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{\log n} \frac{a_k}{k} |  \\ $

Comment: Thanks  a lot of r9m I'll review your proof

Comment: @Rastalovely sorry .. I'm finding it difficult to understand what you have tried. Most of it makes no sense to me.

Comment: @kayak That's unnecessary I suppose, the Stolz-Cesaro guarantees both existence and equality of the limit.

Comment: Then why did you say $\displaystyle \left|\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{\sigma_j}{j+1}\right| \le C\sum\limits_{j=1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{j+1} < C \log n$?